# indice inicial de uma lista depois de usar set

Tags: python, python-2.7

Usei este código inicialmente para agregar em dicionários os valores de `B` que tinham igual valor em `A`:

```
A = [12,   15,  10,  15,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  12,  12,  15,  15,  15]
B = [0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]

ASemRepetidos = set(A)

def indicesDeElementoNaLista(elementoProcurado, lista):
    return [i for (i, elemento) in enumerate(lista) if elemento == elementoProcurado]

def elementosNasPosicoes(lista, posicoes):
    return [lista[i] for i in posicoes]

dicionarioResultante = {} 

for elemento in ASemRepetidos:
    posicoes = indicesDeElementoNaLista(elemento, A)
    elementosCorrespondentes = elementosNasPosicoes(B, posicoes)
    dicionarioResultante[elemento] = elementosCorrespondentes

print(dicionarioResultante)
```

E o resultado foi:

```
{10: [1.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6], 12: [0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7], 15: [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]}
```

Mas ao fazer isto, o `set(A)` altera-me a ordem dos elementos e eu precisava da ordem original de `A` para encontrar numa 3ª lista os valores desta que tivessem o mesmo indice que `A` e não que `ASemRepetidos`, pois esta lista é muito menor que `A`, além de estar "desordenada" devido à aplicação do set.
Como é que eu posso saber o índice dos repetidos a primeira vez que eles aparecem na lista original `A` e não o seu índice na lista de sem repetidos (`ASemRepetidos`)? Ou seja, eu queria uma função geral que me retornasse que o índice de 12 é 0, que o de 15 é 1 e que o de 10 é 2?
Tentei fazer:

```
indice=[] 
for k in range(0,len(A)):
    for chave in ASemRepetidos: 
        indice.append(A.index(chave)) 
print indice
```

mas não deu...
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Por que `A.index(valor)` não deu certo?

Comment: não é isso que eu quero, expressei-me mal..
ao aplicar o set este desordena-me as listas iniciais... Imagine que a lista A é um código, e portanto sempre que esse codigo é igual, os elementos correspondentes da lista B e C, etc são iguais.. e no final só me interessa que o programa apresente 1 valor(dos vários que são iguais), para cada chave e para cada lista, percebe a minha duvida e o que pretendo fazer?

Comment: Mas `set()` não modifica a lista original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se percebi bem o que estás a tentar fazer a solução seguinte deverá resolver o problema:

```
indice=[]
feitos = [] # vou guardar aqui todas as chaves que já ocorreram no loop.
indic = {} # Se quiseres ter uma ligação directa entre chave e indice...
for k in A:
    if k in ASemRepetidos and k not in feitos: 
        indice.append(A.index(k))
        feitos.append(k)
        indic[k]=A.index(k)
print(indice)
print(indic)
```

Repara que meti um dicionário que não é necessário à resolução do problema mas ajuda a confirmar os valores pedidos por ti. O dicionário tem como chave os valores de A e como valor os indices das ocorrências. O resultado é:

```
[0, 1, 2]
{10: 2, 12: 0, 15: 1}
```

Comment: Agora precisava de manter esta ordem dos indices, mas somar os valores sempre que o codigo é o mesmo, ou seja sempre que o valor em A é o mesmo.. 
Eu já tinha o dicionario feito e para este caso 10: [1.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6], bastaria fazer sum(1.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6), mas como foi aplicado o set, isso ordena-me os valores de forma estranha e não me dá a ocorrencia de cada um pela ordem em que aparece na lista original.. Ou seja, pela sua resposta retirei os  indices necessários a ir procurar os seus valores numa lista C, mas os indices do dicionário não correspondem a estes.. o que devo fazer?

Comment: @SofiaRaimundo Eu não estou a conseguir perceber o problema. Penso que é melhor abrires uma nova questão com o codigo que te està a dar o problema bem como o output que esperas ter. Mete o link aqui que eu tento ver como se resolve.

Comment: aqui está: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122264/desordem-da-lista-ao-aplicar-set @armatita