# Remover duplicatas de uma lista mantendo a ordem

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu tinha a lista:

```
A = [12,   15,  10,  15,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  12,  12,  15,  15,  15]
```

, ao fazer:

```
ASemRepetidos=set(A)
```

fico com `([10, 12, 15])`, como se vê, se em `A` o meu primeiro elemento é o 12, em `set(A)` passa a ser 10, ou seja eu perco a ordem original dos elementos...

Se:

`B=[0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]`

Ao fazer este código:

```
indice=[]
feitos = [] # vou guardar aqui todas as chaves que já ocorreram no loop.
indic = {} # Se quiseres ter uma ligação directa entre chave e indice...
for k in A:
    if k in ASemRepetidos and k not in feitos: 
        indice.append(A.index(k))
        feitos.append(k)
        indic[k]=A.index(k)
obtenho os indices da 1ª ocorrencia de cada valor repetido e portanto posso fazer:
Re=[]
for g in indice:
    Re.append(B[g])
```

obtendo da lista `B` os valores do 1º índice que se repete.
Mas se em vez de querer apenas o valor do 1º índice repetido quiser a soma de cada conjunto repetido, mas de todos os conjuntos, e mantendo a ordem de ocorrência da chave desses conjuntos em `A` e não do `set(A)` como faço?

Eu já tinha este dicionário:

```
ASemRepetidos = set(A)

def indicesDeElementoNaLista(elementoProcurado, lista):
    return [i for (i, elemento) in enumerate(lista) if elemento == elementoProcurado]

def elementosNasPosicoes(lista, posicoes):
    return [lista[i] for i in posicoes]

dicionarioResultante = {} 

for elemento in ASemRepetidos:
    posicoes = indicesDeElementoNaLista(elemento, A)
    elementosCorrespondentes = elementosNasPosicoes(B, posicoes)
    dicionarioResultante[elemento] = elementosCorrespondentes
print(dicionarioResultante)

e para a soma de cada conjunto fazia:
A = [12,   15,  10,  15,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  12,  12,  15,  15,  15]
print set(A)
B = [0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]
B_lin = {} # coloque um nome mais adequado ao seu contexto

for elemento in set(A):
    posicoes = indicesDeElementoNaLista(elemento, A)
    elementosCorrespondentes = elementosNasPosicoes(B, posicoes)
    B_lin[elemento] = elementosCorrespondentes
B_Total=[]
for chave in set(A):
    B_Total.append(sum(B_lin[chave]))
    print chave, B_lin[chave]
#print B_Total
```

e obtinha:

```
set([0, 1088, 1602, 1089, 9999, 1107, 1615, 1616, 1010, 1011, 1108, 1015, 1114, 1115])
set([10, 12, 15])
10 [1.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6]
12 [0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7]
15 [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]
```

ou seja o set ordena do `10-12-15`, enquanto que eu precisava que a ordem se mantivesse: `12-15-10`, porque depois os resultados da pesquisa dos elementos por índice na lista não são coerentes com os apresentados nesta função da soma e a ideia é os valores serem no final passados para um Excel pela forma em que surgem inicialmente.

Se em vez da soma quiser o mínimo de cada conjunto faço:

```
Ili = []
listas_min = []
ind=[]
for i in range(len(indice)):
    valor = A[indice[i]]
    listas_min.append([])
    for j in range(len(A)):
        if A[j]==valor:
            listas_min[i].append(B[j])
            ind.append(j)
    Ili.append(min(listas_min[i]))
#print(Ili)
print ind
```

e funciona, dá-me o valor mínimo para cada conjunto. Tentei retornar também o respectivo índice da lista original (`A`) e não em `ASemRepetidos` em que isso acontece, através de `.index` mas não não consegui.

Comment: O minimo de cada conjunto não tem um indice respectivo mas sim o conjunto dos indices. È isto que pretendes? Se sim guarda o j no loop quando A[i]==valor.

Comment: em que sitio mesmo do código é que tenho que guardar? não está a dar...

Comment: Logo a seguir a listas[i].append(B[j]). Faz outra lista como a "listas" para guardar os indices.

Comment: Tive que fazer uma alteração de novo no código porque não estava a calcular bem os mínimos, agora já está mas se fizer isso que dizes não dá.. dá-me os índices todos em vez de dar o do valor do mínimo de cada conjunto...

Comment: Pensei que era isso que querias. Editei o fim da resposta com codigo para tirares o indice do minimo de cada conjunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se percebi o problema bem então a seguinte solução deverà resolver o problema:

```
somas = []
listas = []
for i in range(len(indice)):
    valor = A[indice[i]]
    soma = 0
    listas.append([])
    for j in range(len(A)):
        if A[j]==valor:
            soma = soma + B[j]
            listas[i].append(B[j])
    somas.append(soma)
print(indice)                  # Indice correcto
print([A[i] for i in indice])  # Valores de A nos indices correctos
print(somas)                   # Somas por cada indice correcto
print(listas)                  # listas por cada indice correcto (que foram somadas)
```

, o resultado é:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[12, 15, 10]
[1.4, 2.0, 2.8000000000000003]
[[0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7], [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5], [1.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6]]
```

, e este codigo foi corrido logo a seguir a encontrares os valores do primeiro indice que se repete:

```
indice=[]
feitos = [] # vou guardar aqui todas as chaves que já ocorreram no loop.
indic = {} # Se quiseres ter uma ligação directa entre chave e indice...
for k in A:
    if k in ASemRepetidos and k not in feitos: 
        indice.append(A.index(k))
        feitos.append(k)
        indic[k]=A.index(k)
```

**EDITADO:**

Para teres os minimos e e indices dos minimos:

```
minimos = []
indminimos = []
for i in listas:
    minimos.append(min(i))
    indminimos.append(B.index(min(i)))
print(minimos)
print(indminimos)
```

, que resulta em:

```
[0.2, 0.1, 0.4]
[0, 8, 6]
```

Comment: Quando faço o minimo em vez da soma faço assim:

minimos = []
listas_min = []
for i in range(len(indice)):
    valor = A[indice[i]]
    listas_min.append([])
    for j in range(len(A)):
        if A[j]==valor:
            #minimos.append(min(I_ac2[j]))
            listas_min[i].append(B[j])
    minimos.append(min(listas_min[i]))
print minimos

e funciona, dá-me o valor mínimo para cada conjunto. Tentei retornar também o respetivo indice da lista original (A) e não em ASemRepetidos em que isso acontece, através de .index mas não não consegui...

Comment: @SofiaRaimundo È bastante dificil perceber codigo a partir de um comentario. Faz uma edição na tua pergunta ou abre uma questão nova (eu sugiro que abras novas questões para novas perguntas caso contràrio os posts ficam confusos e desnecessariamente longos).

Comment: Já editei, portanto a minha dúvida agora é só a última parte, relativa ao indice do mínimo @armatita